# How set id via Exposed

Tags: kotlin-exposed

I create object and dao class for work with sql

```
object UserTable : IdTable<Int>("User") {
    val parameters = reference("search_parameters_id", SearchParametersTable)

    override val id = integer("id").entityId()
    override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(id)
}

class User(id: EntityID<Int>) : Entity<Int>(id) {
    companion object : EntityClass<Int, User>(UserTable)

    var searchParameters by SearchParameters referencedOn UserTable.parameters
}
```

But I cann't set id, beacause id is val

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to insert a record with an arbitrary `id`
    value? If yes, you can write like below.

```
val newId = 10
User.new(newId) {
    // set values to other columns
}
```